# How can I sort an ArrayList of arrays based on the array[0] element which is a date given in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a small issue in which I need to sort an arraylist of arrays based on the arrays 0th index. For example If I have an array list containing string arrays such as this:

```
arr1[0] = "12/21/2018" 
arr1[1] = "California"
arr[n] = "some string"

// and I have another array 
arr2[0] = "11/21/2018" 
arr1[1] = "California"
arr[n] = "some string".
```

How would I go about sorting the arraylist based on the 0th index of each array in the array list?

Comment: You chose this data structure? Well, you shouldn't do it like this. Instead, create a class with a bunch of fields representing the data you're actually holding. For instance, "12/21/2018" must be some date, and "California" must be some state. Java is an object-oriented language, so use it as such.

Comment: "A" idea is to use a third array to maintain indices to the original array(s).  In this way, you psudo sort the third array so that `sort[0]` would store the index into the other arrays, this saves a lot of effort.  However, the problem you will have is trying to sort a `String`.  The "better" solution would be to convert the `String` to a `LocalDate` value, which has the capacity to be "compared"

Comment: You can get the array using ArrayList.get(index). Once it returns an array, you can use the brackets on the array to get a specific element in the array. For example, if your ArrayList was called list, using list.get(0)[0] would return the 1st value of the array at index 0 in the ArrayList. Also, when you want to sort it by the first value, do you want to sort it by alphabetical, chronological, etc? If you are sorting by alphabetical you can just use the String.compareTo() method. You are better off making a custom class that would store this data. It would make more sense.

Comment: *"I did choose this type of data structure"* - so, immediately, I'd suggest using a class to encapsulate the properties, it will be much easier to maintain

Comment: You may find this a useful code fragment, which converts not comparable `dd/mm/yyyy` format into naturally comparable `yyyymmdd` format: `String yyyymmdd = ddmmyyyy.replaceAll("(..).(..).(.*)", "$3$2$1");`

Comment: Your title says "dd/mm/yyyy" but your example data is "mm/dd/yyyy". Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with putting an `Array` of `Strings` inside an `ArrayList`, why not just create a new class with properties? This class could implement `Comparable` so we can add a custom compare function that would allow us to sort the list in a custom fashion. For example, your class could be called *Location*, and has a `LocalDate` date (as mentioned by MadProgrammer), and a `String` name. An example would look a bit like this:

```
class Location implements Comparable<Location> {

// We implement the Comparable so we can Override the compareTo() method and make a custom
// sorting method.

    LocalDate date;
    String name;

    // Add more properties as needed...

    public Location(LocalDate d, String n) {
    // Constructor to help us create the object

        this.date = d;
        this.name = n;

    }

// I'm assuming you are comparing the String that was in the first index of the array as
// Dates in chronological order. That way we can compare them easily like so.
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Location other) {

        return this.date.compareTo(other.date);

    }

}
```

You could create an `ArrayList` of the `Location` class, which would be defined as something like this:

```
List<Location> locs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, you can sort it using `Collections.sort(List<T> list)`. It sorts it using the comparator that was made in the class.

---

Java is Object Oriented. Use it to your advantage to avoid sticky situations like these.

Comment: Ah yes this makes alot of sense, when we get our full project I will def use this approach, it makes alot of sense thanks and helped me realize much more!

Comment: No problem. Object-oriented programming is designed to get yourself out of situations like these and make code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Like Pulse I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API:

```
List<String[]> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
arraylist.add(new String[] { "12/21/2018", "California", "some string"});
arraylist.add(new String[] { "11/21/2018", "California", "some other string"});

DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");
Comparator<String[]> cmpr = Comparator.comparing(arr -> LocalDate.parse(arr[0], dateFormatter ));
arraylist.sort(cmpr);

arraylist.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

Output with the example data given is:

> ```
> [11/21/2018, California, some other string]
> [12/21/2018, California, some string]
> ```

**Link 1:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
**Link 2**: [Answer by Pulse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63733099/how-can-i-sort-an-arraylist-of-arrays-based-on-the-array0-element-which-is-a-d/63733308#63733308).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a one-liner when data is as per **title**, ie `dd/mm/yyyy`:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, comparing(a -> a[0].replaceAll("(..).(..).(.*)", "$3$2$1")));
```

---

Here's a one-liner when data is as per **example**, ie `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, comparing(a -> a[0].replaceAll("(..).(..).(.*)", "$3$1$2")));
```